# Is "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version" wrong?

Tags: kotlin

The following Code 1 is from webpage http://www.tellmehow.co/kotlin-anko-coroutines/

**Code 1**

```
dependencies { 
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version" 
}
```

It seems that the Code 1 is wrong, it should be Code 2, right?

**Code 2**

```
dependencies { 
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$anko_version" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any mention of `anko-common` or `anko-commons` in the linked article, but I'll still answer.

Code 1 is correct. See the [readme](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/README.md#using-anko) on GitHub:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
```

`anko-common` was [renamed in 0.10](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/releases/tag/v0.10)

> `anko-common` artifact renamed to `anko-commons` to reflect the naming changes. `anko-common` is deprecated;

**TL;DR:** Use `anko-commons`, `anko-common` was renamed and deprecated